# Aliasing in Set and Get?

Tags: java

I have this`Point` Class:

```
public class Point
{
    private final int CONSTANT_VALUE = 0;
    private int _x;
    private int _y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
         _x = x;
             _y = y;
    }

    public Point(Point other)
    {
          _x = other._x;
          _y = other._y;
    }

public int getX()
{
    return _x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return _y;
}

public void setX(int x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        _x = CONSTANT_VALUE;
    else
        _x = x;
}

public void setY(int y)
{
    if (y < 0)
        _x = CONSTANT_VALUE;
    else
        _y = y;
}

public void move (int dX, int dY)
{
    int newXValue = _x + dX; 
    int newYValue = _y + dY;

    if (newXValue >= 0 || newYValue >= 0)
    {
        _x = _x + dX;
        _y = _y + dY;
    }   
}
}
```

And City Class:

```
public class City
{
    private String _cityName;
    private Point _cityCenter;
    private Point _centralStation;
    private long _numOfResidents;
    private int _noOfNeighborhoods;
    private final long RESIDENTS_CONST_VALUE = 0;
    private final int NEIGHBORHOODS_CONST_VALUE = 1;

    public City(String cityName, Point cityCenter,
        Point centralStation, long numOfResidents, int noOfNeighborhoods)

    {
        _cityName = cityName;
        _cityCenter = cityCenter;
        _centralStation = centralStation;
        if (numOfResidents < 0)
            _numOfResidents = RESIDENTS_CONST_VALUE;
        else
            _numOfResidents = numOfResidents;
        if (noOfNeighborhoods <= 0)
            _noOfNeighborhoods = NEIGHBORHOODS_CONST_VALUE;
        else                
            _noOfNeighborhoods = noOfNeighborhoods;;
    }

    public City(City other)
    {
        _cityName = other._cityName;
        _cityCenter = new Point(other._cityCenter);
        _centralStation= new Point(other._centralStation);
        _numOfResidents = other._numOfResidents;
        _noOfNeighborhoods = other._noOfNeighborhoods;      
    }

    public String getCityName()
    {
        return _cityName;
    }

    public Point getCityCenter()
    {
        return _cityCenter;
    }

    public Point getCentralStation()
    {
        return _centralStation;
    }

    public long getNumOfResidents()
    {
        return _numOfResidents;
    }

    public int getNoOfNeighborhoods()
    {
        return _noOfNeighborhoods;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName)
    {
        _cityName = cityName;
    }

    public void setCityCenter(Point cityCenter)
    {
        _cityCenter = cityCenter;
    }

    public void setCentralStation(Point centralStation)
    {
        _centralStation = centralStation;
    }

    public void setNumOfResidents(long numOfResidents)
    {
        _numOfResidents = numOfResidents;
    }

    public void setNoOfNeighborhoods(int noOfNeighborhoods)
    {
        _noOfNeighborhoods = noOfNeighborhoods;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "City Name: " + _cityName + "\n" + 
                "City Center: " + _cityCenter + "\n" +
                "Central Station: " + _centralStation + "\n" +
                "Number of Residents: " + _numOfResidents + "\n" +
                "Number of Neighborhoods: " + _noOfNeighborhoods;               
    }

    public boolean addResidents(long residentsUpdate)
    {
        long newResidentAmount = _numOfResidents + residentsUpdate;

        if (newResidentAmount < 0)
        {
            _numOfResidents = 0;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            _numOfResidents = newResidentAmount;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void moveCentralStation(int deltaX,int deltaY)
    {
        _centralStation.move(deltaX, deltaY);
    }

    public double distanceBetweenCenterAndStation()
    {
        return _cityCenter.distance(_centralStation);
    }

    public City newCity(String newCityName, int dX, int dY)
    {
        Point newCityCenterPoint = new Point(_cityCenter);
        newCityCenterPoint.move(dX, dY);

        Point newCityCentralStationPoint = new Point(_centralStation);
        newCityCentralStationPoint.move(dX, dY);

        return new City(
                newCityName, 
                newCityCenterPoint,
                newCityCentralStationPoint, 
                0, 
                1);
    }
}
```

My question:

1. Point class: method public Point(Point other) - do i need to write this i other way to avoid aliasing ?
2. what about the rest get and set method from both `Point` and `City`  classes ? i need to write it in other way or this is OK ?

Comment: I personally prefer the short if, if the code is so short: `_x = x < 0 ? CONSTANT_VALUE : x;`, but this is a matter of taste. But By the way, CONSTANT_VALUE is not defined anywhere, so you should define it and give it a meaningful name.

Comment: why are you prefixing "_" with the variables ?

Comment: Kinjal: This is my homework and this the way i have to define it @user hichaeretaqua: CONSTANT_VALUE added, i forgot it

Answer (score 1):

- There looks to be a bug in `setY`: it assigns to `_x` instead of `_y`.
- This code can avoid aliasing problems on small classes like `Point` by making them immutable. That is, remove the `setX` and `setY` methods from `Point`. Any time a change needs to be made to a point, construct a new `Point` entirely.

`moveCentralStation` then becomes:

```
class Point {
    ...
    Point makeMovedPoint(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        return new Point(_x + deltaX, _y + deltaY);
    }
    ...
}

class City {
    ...
    void moveCentralStation(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        _centralStation = _centralStation.makeMovedPoint(deltaX, deltaY);
    }
    ...
}
```

`City` can be made immutable in a similar fashion. However, that might end up crossing a line and make things less maintainable.

Comment: Point move added, i cannot remove setX and setY methods from Point because that what i need to write (homework) and i cannot add new method except what define in my homework